# Spring REST design for PUT updates of child references with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, put

So I was looking at the `@PutMapping` example at the Spring website https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

I noticed that they call the database to get the `Employee` entity with that `id` and then update the entity from the repository with the name and role from the request.

```
  @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
  Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

    return repository.findById(id)
      .map(employee -> {
        employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
        employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
        return repository.save(employee);
      })
      .orElseGet(() -> {
        newEmployee.setId(id);
        return repository.save(newEmployee);
      });
  }
```

That's great for a small example demo, but how do you handle this on a more complex entity?

What if `Employee` had a list of `Laptops`

Lets suppose that the list in JSON looks something like

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "role": "MyRole",
  "laptops": [
    {
       "model": "abc",
       "serial": "123"
    },
    {
       "model": "xyz",
       "serial": "789"
    },
  ]
}
```

Of course if your mapping is correct from the repository you'll get back an `Employee` entity with the list of laptops and the laptops id on the Java side.

But if the user request for the laptop looks something like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "role": "MyRole",
  "laptops": [
    {
       "model": "abcModified",
       "serial": "123"
    },
    {
       "model": "newModel-xyz was actually removed from the list",
       "serial": "456"
    },
  ]
}
```

1. What would you do in this scenario? Were we suppose to send back the foreign keys?
2. If we were to send the foreign key what would stop someone from referencing foreign that didn't belong to the entity?
3. How do you property map a complex object that may contain list of objects that has other list that was modified.

Edit: I'm calling the `Employee` path because lets say I need to update the `role` and the list of `laptops`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To update a nested field like laptops, it makes more sense to have another method. And if the user tries to update an object that doesn't exists the method should return en error.

Comment: You may want to consider a _subresource_ model like `/users/{userId}/laptops/{laptopId}`.

Answer (score 0):

First when you want to update the child object with parent without child entity id, then you have to delete previous children and create again.

You can send child id when in get API so that you can send them when update. Then for put request, you can find those children by id and update them and add new one if available.

But the best way is to write separate API for the child entity also. Update existing child with id and reference with foreign key and create new with separate API.

Comment: Hmmm sounds like either the first or second recommendation is what I might need. And I might not have been clear in the original post, but I'm sending it as part of ```Employee``` because lets say I'm updating the ```role``` and the ```laptops```.